# Tag suggestion for h2o vs. h2o

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [h2o](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/h2o) tag is being used for the machine learning system (http://h2o.ai/). Until today it had 172 tagged questions.

The newest one, [number 173](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37874787), is obviously about a different H2O! https://h2o.examp1e.net/

What is the usual procedure here? Call the new tag [h2o-http]?

Comment: Retag that one as h2o-server or -http or something else more specific.

Comment: The ICAAN allowed the examp1e.net domain to be sold?

Comment: On the other hand, is a pure webserver question on topic anyways?

Comment: I'm a heavy user of the ML H2O, but to be fair perhaps `h2o-ml` and `h2o-http`. Perhaps also `h2o-r`, `h2o-python`, etc (H2O is a .jar app that has special libraries in R, Python, etc or simply `h2o-0xdata`.

Comment: Is the latter even a legit framework? http://examp1e.net has an invalid ssl cert and a page contents of `hello`. The company linked at the bottom of https://h2o.examp1e.net/ (DeNA) looks... Questionable "The logo's initial letter D is also a smile emoticon, symoblising our ongoing pursuit of customer delight"

Comment: @Basic [There does appear to be valid source for the h2o webserver](https://github.com/h2o/h2o/).

Comment: @Braiaim from the [whois](http://whois.domaintools.com/examp1e.com): `Registrant Organization: A Bad Examp1e`.  At least they have a sense of humor :)

Comment: @Basic DeNA is a big company in Japan. The international site might be plain, but [the Japanese](http://dena.com/jp/) one certainly doesn't look questionable.

Comment: @AndrewT. Good to know, thanks. I'm not qualified to offer an opinion either way, but it's surprising that such a large company can't get an SSL cert right.

Comment: @Basic why would they care for an SSL cert for a webpage they don't use? h2o.examp1e.net has a good cert

Comment: @SztupY We're so far OT here that I'm going to delete this in a few hours... If they don't use it, why does it have even have a web server, let alone one that's trying to talk SSL with an invlid cert isntalled? Just seems untidy and half-implemented. But... AS I said above, I'm not arguing against them, I just made an observation that it looked questionable. It's not. Problem solved